# Nuxt Seo meta-description

Tags: nuxt.js, seo, google-search

I'm following the documentation for seo of https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/
in a netifly hosted nuxt project wwww.estudiosclaw.com

the problem when i run the lighthouse checker in chrome it says the meta description is empty ( apeears in the head of the html ).

when i retieve a especific post directly all checks are red.

in google search typing "estudios claw" only appears the navbar titles.

I have set all my meta description individually depending the page.

example:

```
head() {
    return {
      title: `${this.about.data.attributes.title}`,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: `${this.about.data.attributes.title} - Estudios Claw`,
          content: `${this.about.data.attributes.description}`,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a meta tag like `<meta name=description content="This is the description of the page.">`.  Your code would not do that.  The example code you linked to shows that both the `hid` and the `name` should be `"description"` (literally.)  You appear to be putting the page title into the `name` attribute of the `<meta>` tag, which is not correct.  Correct code should be more like:

```js
head() {
    return {
      title: `${this.about.data.attributes.title} - Estudios Claw`,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: `${this.about.data.attributes.description}`,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Comment: Thanks Stepen, i thought the name field was another thing, still need to tweak for multilanguaje and especific post but I'm in the right track.

For the google search still unsolve, i have compared with another project and shows diferent, i thinkg is a problem with namecheap services, i was using the same domain for a project in their hosting and now I'm using the domain in netifly.